# PHP round & ceiling not correctly parsing data

Tags: php, xml, math, rounding, ceil

The numbers that are being pulled from an xml file and then assigned to a variable but are outputted incorrectly. I'm not quite sure why or how to get around it.  An example is this.

```
$pricing_high = 1.15;
echo $pricing_high;
```

This displays 1.15 obviously. But when I assign this like so:

```
$price = ceil($pricing_high / 0.05) * 0.05;
echo $price;
```

This displays 2.

```
$price = round($pricing_high / 0.05) * 0.05;
echo $price;
```

This displays 1.

How do I get numbers to correctly round up to the nearest 5 cents when passing it like this?

Comment: Both of those will output `1.15`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of PHP documentation for round function:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php

You can specify precision as second parameter:

```
$pricing_high = 1.15;
$price = round($pricing_high / 0.05, 2) * 0.05;
echo $price;
```

Note value of second parameter 2

Comment: Got it to work with $price = round($pricing_high / 5, 2) * 5; How can I get it to keep the 0s? For example instead of displaying 1 it will display 1.00 or from 0.4 to 0.40

Comment: Nevermind I got it :) $price1 = sprintf("%01.2f", $price); Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 1):

Is `1.15` = 1 dollar and 15 cents? If so:

```
echo sprintf('%.2f', round($price / 0.05) * 0.05); // Rounds to nearest
echo sprintf('%.2f', ceil($price / 0.05) * 0.05); // Rounds up
```

Tests:

```
$price = 1.13;

echo sprintf('%.2f', round($price / 0.05) * 0.05); // Outputs: 1.15
echo sprintf('%.2f', ceil($price / 0.05) * 0.05); // Outputs: 1.15

$price = 1.12;

echo sprintf('%.2f', round($price / 0.05) * 0.05); // Outputs: 1.10
echo sprintf('%.2f', ceil($price / 0.05) * 0.05); // Outputs: 1.15
```

If `1.15` = 1.15 cents then replace `0.05` with `5`.

Answer (score 0):

As ceil() and floor() don't have this precision, you might multiply your results and divide it after.